# strong or b tag html not working in modal react js

Tags: html, reactjs

strong and em tag not working in modal react js , but it's working normally in react or html page . is there is a way to make it work in this modal

> and also one more question how to make a next btn in modal to make the
>   modal like pages , when i click the button it goes to the next modal
>   with out closing the first one ?

```
<Modal 
  show={this.state.show} 
  onHide={this.handleClose} 
  bsSize="large" 
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg"
>
  <Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Title className="f2 pa0">welcome modal.</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <ol>
      <li className="mb-3">hello <strong>There</strong>.</li>
      <li className="mb-3">hi!<b>welcome back</b> <i>MR0B</i> to intro.</li>
    </ol>
    <div className="form-group mt-4">
    </div>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
    <Button className="link dim mb2 dib white bg-purple pointer">done</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Comment: it's going to be tough to troubleshoot this one with a live online sample. If you can recreate in [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent) I'll take a look.

Comment: I would have to guess that your CSS for the modal is overriding the definition for `strong` and `b`. Without a working example, it's hard to say where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936159/roopak-putheveettil yes you can solve this problem by creating  and give it css with font-weight bold and yes thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2643479/ted my bootstrap lib was over riding my css for  , so the solution is to make it in  and give it font weight bold or give the span calssName and also write css with !important to over ride modal css , thanks guys for clarification .

```
<li className="mb-3">hello <span>There</span>.</li>
<li className="mb-3">hi!<span>welcome back</span> <i>MR0B</i> to intro.</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li className="mb-3">hello <div style={{font-weight: 'bold !important'}}>There</div>.</li>
<li className="mb-3">hi!<div style={{font-weight: '700 !important'}}>welcome back</div> <i>MR0B</i> to intro.</li>
```

Try this...

Comment: thank you for clarification , but  i want to ask how to make a next btn in modal to make the modal like pages , when i click the button it goes to the next modal with out closing the first one ?